# pdfmake is returning undefined

Tags: node.js, express, pdfmake, node.js-fs

I am using pdfmake package to generate pdf, but when I am testing it on postman it says undefined.

My app.js -

> const express = require('express')
> const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
> const path = require('path')
>
> const port = 9003
>
> const app = express()
>
> //set the public folder
> app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))
>
> //body parser middle ware
> app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
>
> //Index Route
> app.get('/', (req, res) => {
> //res.send('Hello World');
> res.sendfile('index.html')
> })
>
> const pdfRoute = require('./routes/pdfmake')
> app.use('/pdfMake', pdfRoute)
>
> app.listen(port, () => {
> console.log(`Server running at http://localhost:${port}/`)
> })

My pdfmke.js -

> const express = require('express')
> const router = express.Router()
> const fs = require('fs')
>
> const pdfMake = require('pdfmake/build/pdfmake')
> const pdfFonts = require('pdfmake/build/vfs_fonts')
> pdfMake.vfs = pdfFonts.pdfMake.vfs
>
> router.post('/pdf', (req, res, next) => {
>
> const fname = req.body.fname
> const lname = req.body.lname
>
> var documentDefinition = {
> content: [`Hello ${fname} ${lname}`, 'Nice to meet you!'],
> }
>
> const pdfDoc = pdfMake.createPdf(documentDefinition)
> pdfDoc.getBase64((data) => {
> res.writeHead(200, {
> 'Content-Type': 'application/pdf',
> 'Content-Disposition': 'attachment;filename="filename.pdf"',
> })
>
> const download = Buffer.from(data.toString('utf-8'), 'base64')
> res.end(download)
> })
> })

on my postman - when I am adding body - raw-json :

> {
> "fname": "test",
> "lname":"run"
> }

It returns -
Hello undefined undefinedNice to meet you!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried enclosing the variables using the backtick?

```
var documentDefinition = { content: [Hello \`${fname}\` \`${lname}\`, 'Nice to meet you!'], }
```